# Selective "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error

Tags: ajax, rest, xmlhttprequest

I get this error when I execute a GET request to a remote REST service from a web app running on a local computer, but when I run this through the browser (Chrome) or through "Advanced Rest Client Application" (chrome extension)- everything goes well, but I see that there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' there either!
[image: This client can access with no 'access-control-allow-origin' header, and I can't!]

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* or the actual domain's value from where the client app makes request to REST service present as part of your response header. Chrome browser and Rest client extensions do not need this header present that's why you are able to see correct output there

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for further info